# MenuItem with Streamgeometry as Image

Tags: wpf, menuitem

I have a button with a ContextMenu. So if user click on button, the menuitems are shown. I am having one menuitem where I want to have a Streamgeometry source to be displayed next to the text. The problem comes here in. I would expect to see the Streamgeometry source on the left side and the text next to it, but the Streamgeometry source will not appear on the first visible menuitem since it will show you a small green arrow (pointing to right), where you can hover over it with the mouse and a another menuitem will be shown with the Streamgeometry source and the text. So the question is here, how to make the menuitem with Streamgeometry source appearing in the first menuitem without the green arrow on the right side?

This is what I am currently having as code:

```
<Button>
    <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding DoSomething}">
                    <TextBlock>
                        just test
                        <Path
                            Width="17"
                            Height="20"
                            Data="{StaticResource StreamGeometrySource}"
                            Fill="{StaticResource MyBrush}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

I tried to use the StreamGeometry resource out from the menuitem itself, but this seems to be not working.

So I want to have just a simple menuitem without any backdoor (or another menuitem) showing the StreamGeometry source and the text next to each other.

I did´t find any solution which covers my problem here in the forum and on google.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the StreamGeometrySource is, but give this a try

```
<Button>
    <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding DoSomething}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <TextBlock>
                        just test
                       </TextBlock>
                       <Path
                            Width="17"
                            Height="20"
                            Stretch="Uniform"
                            Data="{StaticResource StreamGeometrySource}"
                            Fill="{StaticResource MyBrush}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

In your example Path is part of textblock that does not work I think

Comment: Forgot to but in stretch (path is not shown without it